# How to find iframe Google map link of my address

Tags: html

How to find iframe Google map link of my address

This is my Google map link

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Brufia+Bakery/@9.5021131,76.3394377,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x3b088460b35890d5:0x61a6c6b1233d99b1?hl=en-US">
```

How to add above address in

Comment: Have a look at the Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the link and click on Share/Embed, here is the result:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3935.0761342219785!2d76.33943771479025!3d9.502107793193625!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3b088460b35890d5%3A0x61a6c6b1233d99b1!2sBrufia+Bakery!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1449819600859" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```